# Referencing external link from javascript in Blogger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I wrote an html code to use in my blogspot. Rather than inserting the javascript directly into the page, I would like to just reference the link that points to an external script located in `Apps Script`. I looked for this answer, but I haven't found any that really show what I need to do.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a webapp and use the endpoint url to return the desire info.

Comment: Are you referring to a `fetch` request? I would like to run an external script instead of getting data

Comment: No.  Just try to build and deploy a webapp you will see what I mean

Comment: You can see the official document of Web Apps at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web . But, there is a limitation of Web Apps. What is the roughly maximum number of concurrent access to the Web Apps? In the current stage, it's 30. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) Also, although I'm not sure what you want to do using the script, there is what Google Apps Script cannot do while Javascript can do. Please be careful about this.